# How to present a modal controller from another modally presented controller in iOS

Tags: ios

How to present a modal controller from another modally presented controller in iOS?

first, present a controller named `sourceSelectorController` modally:

`self.present(sourceSelectorController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

now ,how to present a new controller from `sourceSelectorController` modally?

Comment: Simply call `present` from that controller as well.

Comment: You can use animation for presentViewController.

Comment: call same method in that viewController as well, if you want to present instantly then call the method in viewDidLoad

Comment: @UmairAfzal I want to present them modally, but the second present function does not work

Comment: This probably doesn't answer your question but I would probably question your design if you're trying to present a modal view onto of a model view. What is the context of what's happening in the app at this point?